# C++ boost::bind says inaccessible base class

Tags: c++, inheritance, boost

I am trying to use `boost::bind` to call a member function in a class.  Normally this works fine, but in this particular case my compiler (GCC) is complaining that I am trying to use an inaccessible base class when I am not.

Here is some code that demonstrates the problem.  What am I doing wrong?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/bind.hpp>
#include <boost/function.hpp>

class base
{
    protected:
        void test()
        {
            std::cout << "base::test()\n";
        }
};

class derived: virtual protected base
{
    public:
        using base::test;
};

int main(void)
{
    derived d;

    // This works, calling derived::test(), which in turn calls base::test()
    d.test();

    // This does not work, saying 'base' is an inaccessible base of 'derived',
    // but I am not binding base::test, I am binding derived::test.
    boost::function<void()> fn;
    fn = boost::bind(&derived::test, d);
    fn();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I guess the problem comes from `&derived::test` being of type `void (base::*)()`

Comment: You can make this work by writing `boost::bind((void (derived::*)())&derived::test, d);`. And yes, you need a C-style cast for this trick. (It's defined behaviour AFAIK.)

Comment: @DyP: That sounds sensible: There isn't actually a member function `test` in `derived`. It's just a declared name, but the actual function is `base::test`, and there's only one kind of function pointer.

Comment: @KerrekSB Last time I checked, there were two answers to this question. What happened?

Comment: @DyP: This works, thanks!  Unfortunately when I went to put the solution into my code, it doesn't work complaining `pointer to member conversion via virtual base`.  I've updated the question to include virtual inheritance instead - is your solution still possible?

Comment: @DyP Haha, that's the same as my answer, but why did you think a C-style cast is necessary? Anyway, no it's not a quick fix because it requires the base to be accessible. A compiler bug which makes it work only for a C-style cast is quite conceivable because it hits a corner case: very few C-style casts are invalid at all so the compiler might have forgotten to complain.

Comment: @Potatoswatter Because the C-style cast ignores accessibility ;) [expr.cast]/4 bullet 2 of the second list says so. But this doesn't work for a virtual base class :(

Comment: @DyP: My answer was a complete sham, so I deleted it.

Comment: @KerrekSB No, not really. You were right that the using-decl doesn't introduce a new function, it just introduces an alias. That's the underlying reason why `&derived::test` is (still, despite the using-decl) of type `void (base::*)()`.

Comment: @DyP It ignores accessibility for derived to base conversion, but this is going the other way.

Comment: @DyP: Hm... but I don't have a good, punchy explanation. My above comment is the my best guess, that there is no member function in the derived class. If I find a suitable piece of standard text about function pointers, I might fix up the answer.

Comment: @Potatoswatter Oops, wrong bullet. The next one covers base->derived conversion.

Comment: @KerrekSB [class.member.lookup] might cover this; especially /3 covers using-declarations.

Comment: @DyP: Thank you! I just stole that for my answer, if that's alright :-S

Comment: @DyP Hmm, looks like I mis-remembered the issue; the C-style cast does indeed defeat access. Still I think it's better to satisfy the access requirement by moving the offending access into the class than to resort to C-style notation. Matter of taste, though.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `using` declaration doesn't define a function. It "declares a name" (not a function!), and unhides base names. It's true that the declaration itself has its own accessibility level, which is why you're using it at all in the first place, but to stress again: The using declaration does not declare a new member function. E.g. C++11 7.3.3/11:

> The entity declared by a *using-declaration* shall be known in the context using it according to its definition at the point of the using-declaration.

"Its definition", in your case, is still `void base::test(){}`, and *that* is the entity that is made known to the derived class and referred to by `&derived::test`. You can't get a function pointer of type `void(derived:**)()` from this because there is no such function.

When you say `&derived::test`, the `&`-operator is used, which works like this (5.3.1/3):

> The result of the unary `&` operator is a pointer to its operand. The operand shall be an lvalue or a *qualified-id*. If the operand is a *qualified-id* naming a non-static member `m` of some class `C` with type `T`, the result has type “pointer to member of class `C` of type `T`” and is a prvalue designating C::m.

In my interpretation of the above logic, `&derived::test` "names the non-static member `test` of class `base`". [Thanks to @DyP:] The is formalized in 10.2/3:

> The lookup set for `f` in `C` [...] consists of [...] the declaration set [...]. In the declaration set, *using-declarations* are replaced by the members they designate

If you really want, you can provide a wrapper like this:

```
class derived : protected base
{
public:
    void test() { base::test(); }
};
```

(Curiously, that solution actually *does* hide the base function, which is what we want. Rather than using `using`, we use an explicitly qualified name to refer to the base function.)

Comment: @DanielFrey A using-declaration does not *change* the accessibility of a name, however, it has its own accessibility, see [namespace.udecl]/18.

Comment: @KerrekSB You already had my +1, but still look at DyP's comment. Your "which does precisely nothing" is still misleading in this regard (IMHO).

Comment: @DanielFrey: Yes, absolutely right. Removed. And reworded a bit more.

Answer (score 6):

When the function is called, the implicit `this` argument needs to be converted to the base class. The `using` declaration does not adjust the type of `test` from `base::*` to `derived::*`.

You can perform such adjustment manually:

```
static_cast< void (derived::*)() >( &derived::test )
```

but this likewise requires the base to be accessible. So the complete solution would be to encapsulate the above `static_cast` inside the derived class. Otherwise it should be an accessible base.

Comment: Is there a way to encapsulate this in the derived class, without defining a function that simply calls the matching function in the base class?

Comment: @Malvineous Literally encapsulating it in the derived class would mean a function like `void ( derived::* cast_base_ptmf( void (base::*ptmf)() ) )() const { static_cast< void (derived::*)() >( ptmf ); }`

Comment: Or you could just put the `bind` expression in the derived class member function, which would probably be easier.