# How can I std::bind the method of a base class in this situation?

Tags: c++, c++11

```
class animal {
protected:
    animal() {}
    void eat(int x) {}
};


class human
    : private animal
{
public:
    typedef animal base_type;
    using base_type::eat;
};

class stomach {
public:
    stomach(std::function<void(int)> feed) {}
};

class lady
    : public human
{
public:
    typedef lady        this_type;
    typedef human       base_type;

    lady()
        : base_type()
        , m_Stomach(std::bind(&base_type::eat, this, std::placeholders::_1))
    {
    }

private:
    stomach m_Stomach;
};
```

If client code write down:

```
lady gaga;
```

The compiler complains that `std::bind(&base_type::eat, ...)` is **error C2064: term does not evaluate to a function taking 2 arguments**.

I had found that if the class lady is modified to:

```
class lady
    : public human
{
public:
    typedef lady        this_type;
    typedef human       base_type;

    lady()
        : base_type()
        , m_Stomach(std::bind(&this_type::help_eat, this, std::placeholders::_1))
    {
    }

private:
    void help_eat(int x)
    {
        base_type::eat(x);
    }
    stomach m_Stomach;
};
```

With a help function, the compiler will `std::bind` well. But the code duplicates.

I had also found if changing `std::bind` to lambda `m_Stomach([&](int x){ base_type::eat(x); })`, this can also been compiled.

My question is that is there a better way to use `std::bind` in this situation? If not, I maybe consider the lambda.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that `animal` is a **private** base class of `human` and therefore passing (and storing) `this` (which is of type `lady*`) can not be used to call the method from `animal`. You could fix it making it a public base or by adding a method to `human`:

```
animal* animal_ptr() { return this; }
```

and later bind:

```
std::bind(&base_type::eat, animal_ptr(), std::placeholders::_1)
```

[**Live example**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/86aa3493784bdb9a)

Comment: Sorry but the [Live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/86aa3493784bdb9a) cannot been compiled for mine(VS2012). Do I miss something?

Comment: @cbel: I don't use VS/Windows, sorry. What is the exact error message you get?

Comment: The message is the same as before, that's **error C2064: term does not evaluate to a function taking 2 arguments**

Comment: @cbel I can only guess but it looks like VS does not accept `X::eat` when `X` is not the real/correct class. Seems the solutions you already found (a forwarder method or using a lambda) are your best choice then. (In case you wonder: The code in the live example is correct and accepted by both GCC and Clang, so it's a bug in VS)

Comment: I was able to make it compile in Visual Studio 2010 by changing the following: 1) Make `human` inherit from `protected animal` rather than `private animal`. 2) Remove the now obsolete `using` declaration. 3) Change `std::bind(&base_type::eat, ...` to `std::bind(&lady::eat`. Not sure if these changes are an option for you...

Answer (score 0):

The animal is a private base class of human and although the using-declaration makes the function eat available it does not change the signature `void (animal::*)(int)` of the function.

From 7.3.3 The using declaration

> For the purpose of overload resolution, the functions which are
>   introduced by a using-declaration into a derived class will be treated
>   as though they were members of the derived class. In particular, the
>   implicit this parameter shall be treated as if it were a pointer to
>   the derived class rather than to the base class. **This has no effect on
>   the type of the function, and in all other respects the function
>   remains a member of the base class.**

Hence, the binding (referring to the function type) leads to the error `‘animal’ is an inaccessible base of ‘lady’` (g++).

You can fix it by using a lambda `m_Stomach([this](int x) { this->eat(x); })`,
replacing the using-declaration in human by `void eat(int x) { base_type::eat(x); }` or just do it your way.

Comment: I'm afraid the author is confused with a different error he gets with a VS compiler, not the one considered here. The problem you address here has already been discussed, e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19340190/c-boostbind-says-inaccessible-base-class

Comment: @Ixanezis I think the error C2064 is plain misleading